# Get last price of stock data in python

Tags: python, stock, yahoo-finance

I have searched for this topic and I found some packages that are useful. All what I am trying to get is the last price of any specific ticker such as "MSFT"
Here's a code that I found and it is good

```
import pandas_datareader as pdr
from datetime import datetime

ibm = pdr.get_data_yahoo(symbols='MSFT', start=datetime(2021, 3, 1), end=datetime(2021, 3, 12))
print(ibm['Adj Close'])
```

This works for range of dates. How can I get the last price only without hard-coding the start date or end date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use tail keyword.

```
from datetime import datetime, date

ibm = pdr.get_data_yahoo(symbols='MSFT', start = date.today(), end = date.today())
print(ibm['Adj Close'].tail(1))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. How can I get the price only without date and also round the number to two digits after the decimal?

Comment: I have searched and could get the price only using `ibm['Adj Close'].iloc[0]`.